# Sum of the matrix series

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, operator-theory, matrix-calculus

Let $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be a symmetric matrix which $0\preceq A\preceq I$ ($I$ is identity matrix), and $w_k\in\mathbb R^n$ are arbitrary certain vectors which $\|w_k\|\leq1,\,\,k=0,1,\ldots$ (all norms  are euclidean).

The goal is to obtain an upper bound for vector
$$
 \left\|\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty(I-A)^kAw_k\right\|.
$$

Evidently, this quantity is less than $\sqrt{n}$, but it seems that it should not depend on $n$.

Comment: Please explain your bound of $\sqrt{n}$. I assume it is for the partial sum $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(I-A)^kAw_k$?

Comment: Please, see Hansen's answer.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is symmetric, its unit length eigenvectors $\big\{v_i\big|i\in\{1,2,...,n\}\big\}$ with respective eigenvalues $\big\{\lambda_i\big|i\in\{1,2,...,n\}\big\}$ form an orthogonal basis.  $w_k=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_{ki}v_i$, where $\left|a_{ki}\right|\le 1$ as $\|w_k\|\le 1$.

$$s:=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-A)^kAw_k = \sum_{i=1}^n \Big(\sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-A)^kAa_{ki}\Big) v_i,$$
by Fubini's theorem, since $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\big\|(1-A)^kA\big\|$ absolutely converges.

$$\|s\|^2 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \|u_i\|^2,$$
where $u_i:=\Big(\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (1-A)^kAa_{ki}\Big) v_i = \Big(\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (1-\lambda_i)^k\lambda_ia_{ki}\Big)v_i$.  $$\|u_i\|\le\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (1-\lambda_i)^k\lambda_i\left|a_{ki}\right| \le\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (1-\lambda_i)^k\lambda_i =1.$$
Together with the previous inequality, we conclude $\|s\|\le \sqrt n$.

But I think the sharp bound is $1$, although I can not prove it.

I tried the following example. Let $w_k = v_{j+1},\, j\equiv k \ (\mod n)$. We see $\|u_i\| = \frac{(1-\lambda_i)^j}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (1-\lambda_i)^i}$. The norm bound appears -- I have not checked carefully --- below $1$.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, with real eigenvalues between $0$ and $1$. However, $(I-A)A$ kills off eigenvectors with eigenvalue $1$ and $0$; so you need only consider the eigenvectors with eigenvalues strictly between $0$ and $1$. If there are no eigenvalues between $0$ and $1$, then $(I-A)^{k}A=0$ for $k \ge 1$, and a bound is obvious. Otherwise, let $\lambda_{min}$ and $\lambda_{max}$ be the minimum and maximum eigenvalues of $A$ strictly between $0$ and $1$. Then $\|(I-A)^{k}Aw_{k}\| \le (1-\lambda_{min})^{k}\lambda_{max}\|w_{k}\|\le (1-\lambda_{min})^{k}\lambda_{max}$ for $k \ge 0$, which gives $\lambda_{max}/(1-(1-\lambda_{min}))=\lambda_{max}/\lambda_{min}$ as a bound for the sum.

Comment: So the sum could be arbitrarily large, if there exists one intermediate eigenvalue of $A$ near $1$? But it is easy to show that sum is definitely less than $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Certainly you mean $λ_{max}/(1-(1-λ_{min}))=λ_{max}/λ_{min}$

Comment: @LutzL: thanks for the correction. made the edit.

Comment: @user115538: what do you get if $A=\lambda I$ where $0 < \lambda < 1$?

Answer (score 0):

Just using matrix norms, triangle inequality and geometric series you obtain the bound

$$\frac{\|A\|}{1-\|I-A\|}.$$

---

Let's try to get matrix independent. The spectrum of $(I-A)^kA=(I-A)^k-(I-A)^{k+1}$ consists of the eigenvalues

$$f_k(λ)=(1-λ)^k-(1-λ)^{k+1}$$

for $λ$ ranging over the eigenvalues of $A$. The maximum of the full function on $[0,1]$ is at

$$0=f_k'(λ)=-k(1-λ)^{k-1}+(k+1)(1-λ)^k=(1-λ)^{k-1}(1-(k+1)λ)\implies λ = \frac1{k+1}$$

This would give an estimate that is practically a harmonic series, since

$$f_k(\tfrac1{k+1})=\tfrac1{k+1}(1-\tfrac1{k+1})^k=\tfrac1k(1-\tfrac1{k+1})^{k+1}<\tfrac1ke^{-1}\le e^{-1}(\ln(k)-ln(k-1))$$

However, since there is only a finite number of eigenvalues of $A$, there is a smallest positive one with $\tfrac1{N+1}<λ_{min}\le \tfrac1N$, so that the maximum of $f_k$ for $k>N$ is always taken at $λ_{min}$. So one gets a bound of

\begin{align}
&\|A\|+\frac14+\sum_{k=2}^{N} e^{-1}(\ln(k)-\ln(k-1)+\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty λ_{min}(1-λ_{min})^k\\
\le&\frac54+e^{-1}(\ln(N)-\ln(1))+(1-λ_{min})^{N+1}\\
\le&\frac54+e^{-1}(\ln(Nλ_{min})-\ln(λ_{min}))+e^{-(N+1)λ_{min}}\\
\le&\frac54+e^{-1}\bigl(1+|\ln(λ_{min})|\bigr)
\end{align}

So this complicated expression may be a stricter bound, but still depends on the eigenvalue structure of $A$.

---

Using the recursion formula, one may try the following argument

$$x_+=x+A(w-x)=\tfrac12(x+w)+(A-\tfrac12I)(w-x).$$

Now since $\|A-\tfrac12I\|\le \tfrac12$, we have that $x_+$ is inside a ball with center the midpoint between $x$ and $w$ and so, that $x$ and $w$ are the poles of the ball. However, this ball can have parts outside the unit ball if $x$ and $w$ are close enough to the unit sphere.

Comment: OK, but if $A$ is near $I$, we obtain a huge bound. However, in this case the original sum is very small!

Comment: What is, in your opinion, very small if $\|w_0\|=1$? Then the first term of the sum is $Aw_0$, which is, under the assumption $A\approx I$, close to a unit vector.

Comment: Really, close to unit vector, but not as huge as $\frac{\|A\|}{1-\|I-A\|}$

Comment: I'm not sure that you are interpreting the formula correctly. Because of $A\approx I$, $\|A\|\approx 1$ and $\|I-A\|\approx 0$, so that the whole expression is close to $1$. First you claim that $1$ is very small, next you claim that $1$ is huge, which is not very consistent. Even with the better bound $\kappa(A)=\|A\|\,\|A^{-1}\|=\lambda_{max}/\lambda_{min}$ you get, in this case, a bound close to $1$.

Comment: I'v given another bound, which still depends on the minimal positive eigenvalue. Please explain or give a reference on your claim that there exists a bound that is independent of the matrix. It may be possible to refine my last argument so that one can avoid the harmonic series.

Comment: ОК, let us consider the discrete-time system $x_{k+1}=(I-A)x_k-Aw_k,$ with phase state $x_k$ and disturbances $w_k$; $x_0=0$. Let $0\prec A\preceq I$, so the system is discrete stable (all eigenvalues of $I-A$ are in the unit ball). We want to estimate the maximal possible value of $\|x_k\|$ for $\|w_k\|\leq1$. Evidently, due to stability, this value is bounded for any $0\prec A\preceq I$.

Comment: @user115538: If your original setup is what you described in your last comment, then $x_{k}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^k (1-A)^iA w_{k-i}$, where I took the liberty changing your $-w_i$ to $w_{i+1}$ for aesthetics. This is completely different from your formulation in your question. You should decide which question you want to ask.

Comment: Not different; I'm interesting in evaluation of the $\|x_k\|$ for $k\to\infty$ and in this case I can treat $w_{k-i}$ as arbitrary $w_k$.

Comment: That is exactly where you are wrong! Switching $k-i$ and $k$ makes it two completely different problems. Take two sequences $a_i$ and $b_i$ and try the two different ordering and you will see the distinction.

Comment: Maybe you can more rigorously describe what you intend to do, i.e., "treat it in any order". The way you describe it in your formulation is "given certain vectors $w_k$". In this formulation, the order is essential. As the way it is described, you get different resulting limits from the two formulation. If this mathematical way of reason does not convince you, try this more intuitive physical reasoning. The $k-i$ ordering means the initial data becomes less and less important as time goes by and the most recent data becomes more important. While the $k$ ordering implies the opposite.

Comment: A question has to be clearly stated to be solved. You either describe the problem determinstically or stochastically. However, even in the latter case, the formulation should still be the $k-i$ version. On the physical intuition level, do you agree with what I said before?

Comment: The indices indicate order or time direction. This should not be out of order.

Comment: It seems you have agreed. Then which version of the questions are you going to choose to ask? Please edit the question according to your choice.

Comment: @user115538: If you are still not completely convinced of the distinction, maybe you would like to leave your email here and we can discuss in detail. Also, with the $k-i$ index version, I can show the sharp upper bound is greater than $1$, at least $\sqrt 2$. But with the $k$ index version, I suspect the sharp upper bound is $1$ though I can not prove it.